# Rails 4 collection_check_boxes, with a has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through, checkboxlist, categorization

I'm trying to associate categories to products. 
The way I've implemented it so far is

```
Class Product
    has_many :categorizations
    has_many :categories, through: :categorizations
```

.

```
Class Categorization
    belongs_to :product
    belongs_to :category
```

.

```
Class Category
    has_many :categorizations
    has_many :products, through: :categorizations
```

and in my products/_form.html.erb

```html
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :category_id %><br />
<%= collection_check_boxes(:product, :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name) %>
</div>
```

I'm not sure how to do this properly.

**Solution**
Change : `:category_id` to `:category_ids` and set the strong params

```html
def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, :price, :category_ids => [])
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Being that the relationship is many-to-many a given product should respond to `category_ids` (plural), not `category_id` (singular).

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I also had to set `def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, :image_url, :price, :category_ids => [])
    end`